# Verify parameter of parameter class in moq setup

Tags: c#, moq

```
context.Setup(x => x.ExecuteQuery(It.IsAny<GetBrowserByNameQuery>())).Returns(value: null);
```

Query class:

```
public class GetApplicationByNameQuery : IQuery<Application, Application?>
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public GetApplicationByNameQuery(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public Application? Execute(IQueryable<Application> queryable)
    {
        return queryable.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == _name);
    }
}
```

GetBrowserByNameQuery requires a string, I do not succeed to test the string passed to GetBrowserByNameQuery.

Following example does not work because it's an other instance of GetBrowserByNameQuery

```
context.Setup(x => x.ExecuteQuery(new GetBrowserByNameQuery>(command.Name))).Returns(value: null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try following approach:

```
GetBrowserbyNameQuery resultQuery = null;
context
   .Setup(x => x.ExecuteQuery(It.IsAny<GetBrowserByNameQuery>()))
   .Returns(value: null)
   .Callback<GetBrowserByNameQuery>(query => { resultQuery = query; });
```

Now in `resultQuery` you have an actual instance of class, which was used as argument. And you can assert (if class has some public property for `Name`) with assertion library you use. For example for FluentAssertions:

`resultQuery.Name.Should().Be(command.Name)`

If `GetBrowserByNameQuery` doesn't expose `Name`, there is no easy way to check it. Constructor could not be mocked, so only options you have:

- access private field via reflections, which is super ugly and breaks unit testing principles
- wrap creation of a `GetBrowserByNameQuery` with factory, and then mock the factory and check if factory method was called with a correct argument

Comment: I updated the question with the query class, the name is not exposed :/ Will look into the factory suggestion then

Comment: Please let me know, if you will need implementation help